# How can I view the contents of a System Restore Point in Windows XP?

Tags: windows-xp, system-restore

I found a way of [listing the System Restore Points](http://windowsxp.mvps.org/ListSR.htm), but now I want to view the contents of a system restore point.

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Try ShadowExplorer](http://www.shadowexplorer.com/)

> Features:
>
> Show available point-in-time copies
>
> Browse through Shadow Copies
>
> Retrieve versions of files and folders